# JDialog not finalized

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jdialog

I have a Java Application where JDialog is opened from a button in a JFrame.
I have set default close operation of JDialog to JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

The problem that I the JDialog is not finalized after being closed using the cross button in the dialog window.
After analysing a memory snapshot I came across that this is because parent window's(the JFrame) ownedWindowList still has a reference to the dialog object.

Does anyone know why this could happen and how I can solve it?

Comment: Could you please present your code

Comment: *"I have a Java Application where JDialog is opened from a button in a JFrame."* I am skeptical that this is a memory leak, and even if so, that it causes much problem.  After all, how many (tens of) thousands of dialogs does it take to crash the JVM?  If it **truly is** a problem (OOME), try using a `CardLayout` in a single dialog, or showing the exact same dialog and components with different values in the fields.

Comment: The `ownedWindowList` contains **Weak** References, so this should not prevent the dialog from being reclaimed and garbage collected. But note that this will not done immediately (when you close the dialog), and it might not be done at all during one application run **if** the memory that is occupied by the dialog simply is not required otherwise. Particularly regarding the question: You never know when (or whether) `finalize()` on an object will be called. Websearch: "Effective Java, Item 7: Avoid finalizers"  The rule of thumb is: There's no leak unless you get an `OutOfMemoryError`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm trying right now, and I faced the same problem.
I need an application, that reads some local files, and after more
searching, I found that Java can do more than I was expected...
I had written the skeleton of a Java dialog class for an interface.

The problem was, closing the dialog, was still working in background.
And trying to run again the application, it said it's still running.
Here is the code for my class:

```
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class JFrameDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog 
implements java.awt.event.ActionListener { 
  private static javax.swing.JDialog dialog; 

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
  }

  public static void setup_controls(){
    javax.swing.JButton myButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Close");
    myButton.setVisible(true); 
    myButton.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 30); 
    myButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        System.exit(0); 
      } 
    }); 

    dialog.add(myButton); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    dialog = new javax.swing.JDialog(); 
    dialog.setLayout(null); 
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
    dialog.setTitle(" Area Report"); 
    dialog.setSize(600,400); 
    dialog.setLocation(0, 0);
    
    setup_controls();     
    dialog.setVisible(true); 

    dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter(){
      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { 
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }); 
  } 
}
```

As you can see, the close option is also: JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
But this is not actually removing the program from the working heap.

Once you had detected the windowClosing event, either from the Close button, or from the frame menu close button (that with an X inside), you may call System.exit(0);

This will terminate the application main loop and the dialog will close. Next time when running again the application, the dialog shows normally.

Hopefully this also works for other people.
With kind regards, Adrian Brinas.